# HTTP status code for creating too many resources

Tags: http-status-codes

If there is a limit on the number of resources created using POST request, what should be the status code?

Let's say, there is a restriction on the number of resources created using POST wherein only 10 resources can be created. The 11th POST request should fail due to the above constraint. What should be the status code?

Should it be 422 with a meaningful message, something along the lines of "Resource count limit reached"? or is there a status code for this?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use-case.

If user is limited in time (let's say 10 per day) but might actually get more credits later automatically, I suggest **429 Too Many Requests** as client sent to many requests in one day.
If credits are locked (ie: User only had 10 free credits), I suggest **403 Forbidden** as the request is fully understood and processable but the server does deny it due to lack of credits.

Anyway **422 Unprocessable entity** is not correct as the request is well formed and server might process it with given credits. Nothing is really missing from the request (from what I understand from your post).

Answer (score 0):

I think that HTTP400 is appropriate, especially if you can provide helpful feedback in the error response. If a user is submitting an invalid payload in the request- it's a bad request. Anything else might get confusing.

Though, HTTP405 (Not Allowed) *might* be better. If there are no POST more requests accepted by the server for a particular resource that may be more accurate. However it really just depends on the future use of the API.